# Laravel Links to CSS

Tags: php, html, css, laravel, laravel-routing

I have this one problem I have been thinking to ask since 2013. I have no idea why I have stayed this long.

In Laravel views, I use `{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}` to include a CSS file into a template. That works perfectly for links like `/users`, `/tasks`, `/clients`.

However when I access I file from a link like `/users/create`, `/tasks/1/edit` I get a problem. It is like the CSS file is not included. These two images will elaborate more.

[image: /clients works well]
[image: /clients/create is not picking up]

**Here is create.blade.php file**

```
 @extends('template')

@section('content')

<div class="panel panel-white">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5 class="panel-title">Create Client</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <p class="text-small margin-bottom-20">

        @if($errors->has())
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <ul>
                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                @endforeach
            </ul>
        </div>
        @endif
    </p>

        {{ Form::model($client, array('url'=> $url, 'method'=> $method, 'role'=>'form')) }}

            @include('clients._form')

        {{ Form::close() }}
    </div>
</div>
@stop
```

**Here is the Client's index.blade.php**

```
@extends('template')


@section('content')

        <p class="text-small margin-bottom-20">
            @if(Session::has('success'))
            <div class="alert alert-success">
                {{ Session::get('success') }}
            </div>
            @endif
        </p>


<table class="table table-hover" id="sample-table-1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="center">#</th>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">Contact Person</th>
            <th class="hidden-xs">Email</th>
            <th>Mobile Number</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($clients as $client)
        <tr>
            <td class="center">{{ $client->id }}</td>
            <td class="hidden-xs"><a href="{{ URL::to('clients/'.$client->id) }}">{{ $client->company }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ $client->firstname." ".$client->lastname }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->email }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->phone }}</td>
            <td class="center">
                <div class="visible-md visible-lg hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <a href="{{ URL::to('clients/'.$client->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" tooltip-placement="top" tooltip="Edit">Edit</a>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ Form::open(array('method'=>'delete','action'=> array('ClientController@destroy',$client->id))) }}
                    <button class = 'btn btn-danger btn-xs' type="submit">Delete</button>                      
                {{Form::close()}}
            </td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach

    </tbody>
</table>


<span class="pull-right">{{ $clients->links() }}</span>
@stop
```

**Here is the relevant section of my template.blade.php**

```
<!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content="IE=edge,IE=9,IE=8,chrome=1" /><![endif]-->
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
        <meta content="" name="description" />
        <meta content="" name="author" />
        <!-- end: META -->
        <!-- start: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,400italic,600,700|Raleway:300,400,500,600,700|Crete+Round:400italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <!-- end: GOOGLE FONTS -->
        <!-- start: MAIN CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/themify-icons/themify-icons.min.css') }}">
        <link href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/animate.css/animate.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/perfect-scrollbar/perfect-scrollbar.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="{{ URL::asset('vendor/switchery/switchery.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <!-- end: MAIN CSS -->
        <!-- start: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/styles.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/plugins.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/themes/theme-1.css') }}" id="skin_color" />
        <!-- end: CLIP-TWO CSS -->
        <!-- start: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
        <!-- end: CSS REQUIRED FOR THIS PAGE ONLY -->
    </head>
    <!-- end: HEAD -->
    <body>
```

**EDIT 1**: here is the the link to Logo
[image: Logo]

**EDIT 2:** Here is my error log
[image]

**EDIT 3:** Here are the /clients and /clients/create source code

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks to me like the problem is an image and not the css. Make sure to use `URL::asset()` (or just `asset()`) for all images as well!

Comment: I have put `{{ URL::asset('assets/images/filename.jpg') }}` to all images. Same problem persists

Comment: Well I see a "broken image" symbol in your second screenshot so the problem is definitely an image. Can you show me the code for that part of your site?

Comment: Sure, I have uploaded the screenshot of the code

Comment: Hmm ye that looks fine. You can check two things. First, make sure your browser isn't caching anything and second check the developer console (F12) for a 404 error (there should be one with the image that failed to load)

Comment: What is the actual output of `{{ URL::asset('assets/images/logo.png') }}` when you view source?

Comment: Check the new edit. I have uploaded my error log. Why is the GET request changing the links to the 2 resources ONLY?

Comment: I see in your log it's trying to load `http://project/newinvoice/public/client/assests/images/logo.png` ... What is the correct URL it should be loading?

Comment: The URL is this: `http://project/newinvoice/public/assets/images/logo.png` as indicated on the third screenshot with a red outline

Comment: could you show me the source of url of logo in `/clients` page ?

Comment: @Richie It could be a view caching problem. Try deleting all the cached files in `storage/framework/views`

Comment: @mininoz Check the new screenshots I have added for both `/clients` and `/clients/create` @lukasgeiter I have deleted the cached files. Same problem persists

Comment: omg! I found a JS file that was overriding my CSS. I have managed to comment out the code. Everything works fine now.